# variable of type referenced from scope, but it is not defined

Tags: nhibernate

i'm a newbie nhibernate,i try use Select in Nhibernate like Entity.
This is query

```
var modelDetailEngine = session.QueryOver<CarSpecification>(() => specificationAlias)
                    .Left.JoinAlias(() => specificationAlias.Car, () => carAlias)
                    .Left.JoinAlias(() => carAlias.Year, () => yearAlias)
                    .Left.JoinAlias(() => yearAlias.Model, () => modelAlias)
                    .Left.JoinAlias(() => modelAlias.Style, () => styleAlias)
                    .Left.JoinAlias(() => styleAlias.Manufacturer, () => manufactureAlias)
                    .Where(() => manufactureAlias.Id == manufactureId && modelAlias.Id == modelId && yearAlias.Id == yearId)
                    .Select(p => new ModelDetailEngineDto()
                    {
                        EngineName = p.Engine,
                        EngineType = p.Type_Engine,
                        CompressionRatio = p.Compresstion,
                        DrivingType = p.Driving_Type,
                        TranmissionType = p.Transmission_Type,
                        FuelType = p.Fuel_Type,
                        FuelEconomyCity = p.Fuel_Economy_City,
                        FuelEconomyHighway = p.Fuel_Economy_Highway,
                        Locking = p.Locking,
                        EngineValvetrain = p.Engine_Valvetrain,
                        ESS = p.ESS,
                        EBD = p.EBD,
                        RemoteVehicle = p.Remote_Vehice,
                        Tranmission = p.Transmission,
                        ExteriorLength = p.Exterior_Length,
                        ExteriorWidth = p.Exterior_Width,
                        ExteriorHeight = p.Exterior_Height,
                        HorsePower = p.Horsepower,
                        Torque = p.Torque,
                        DragCoeficient = p.Drag_Coeficient,
                        TimeSpeed = p.TimeSpeed,
                        Km = p.Km,
                        CurbWeight = p.Curb_Weight,
                        GVWR = p.GVWR
                    }).SingleOrDefault<ModelDetailEngineDto>();
```

**Error** variable 'p' of type referenced from scope, but it is not defined

i don't understand what wrong with it.please help me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot project with [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover) by using [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) syntax. [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover) is not a Linq provider, it is a distinct API with its own semantics. You have to use [QueryOver syntax](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryqueryover.html#queryqueryover-projections), as illustrated in many answers on Stack Overflow ([here](/a/10539099/1178314) by example).

In short, lambda in [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover) are mostly used for identifying only one entity property per lambda. (With the exception of `Where` conditions being a bit more versatile, but only for [simple expressions](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryqueryover.html#queryqueryover-simpleexpressions).) Lambda are not used and supported for expressing elaborated projection in a single lambda, as with Linq. You must decompose it in as many lambda as properties used. Then transform it with a result transformer into your DTO.

Or instead, use [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate):

```
using System.Linq;
using NHibernate.Linq; // This using is mandatory with older NHibernate, not with newer NH

// ...

var modelDetailEngine = session.Query<CarSpecification>()
    .Where(cs => ...)
    .Select(cs => new ModelDetailEngineDto
    {
        // ...
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```